# CSS marquee not showing all data

Tags: css

I have a simple CSS marquee scrolling data up which works great but it stops displaying the data after about 10 lines. If I make it bigger, it just makes a mess of the page.

Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <h3>AREAS COVERED</h3><h5><div class="microsoft areas">
    <p class="marquee"><? echo $areas ?></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.areas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee {
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* Make it move! */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { top:   8em }
    100% { top: -11em }
}

/* Make it look pretty */
.microsoft .marquee {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font: 1em 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.microsoft:before, .microsoft::before,
.microsoft:after,  .microsoft::after {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%; height: 2em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFF, rgba(255,255,255,0));
}

.microsoft:after, .microsoft::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.microsoft:before, .microsoft::before {
    top: 0;

}
```

The areas.php file is about 100 lines in this format:

```
WestMidlands
WestSussex
WestYorkshire
Wiltshire
```

it's loading everything just stopping displaying it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this what you're going for? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEmXjE

Comment: Mate thankyou it works a treat! Cant exactly see what you have changed yet but thankyou anyway!!!

Comment: I'll submit it as an answer with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your animation should go from `top: 100%;` to `top: 0; transform: translateY(-100%)`.

`top: 100%` will put the top of the marquee at the bottom of it's container.

`top: 0; transform: translateY(-100%);` will put the bottom of the marquee at the top of it's container.

```css
.areas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}


/* Make it move! */

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}


/* Make it look pretty */

.microsoft .marquee {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font: 1em 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

.microsoft:before,
.microsoft::before,
.microsoft:after,
.microsoft::after {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}

.microsoft:after,
.microsoft::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.microsoft:before,
.microsoft::before {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <h3>AREAS COVERED</h3>
  <div class="microsoft areas">
    <p class="marquee">
      WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire WestMidlands WestSussex WestYorkshire Wiltshire
    </p>
  </div>
```