# Auto scrolling if overflow hidden

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a bunch of  where the text in them may be longer than the width is. I have overflow set to hidden. Because this is being displayed on a huge tv, I need the info in the  that has hidden overflow to auto scroll after perhaps 10 seconds, to display the rest of the info, and then reset back to its original place, or possibly continue around 360, I am not sure which is best.

```
<td class='left'>
    <div>
        <img src='../img' width='$wide'>
        <div class='num' valign='top' id='" . $sNum . ";'>$sNum</div>
        <div class='name' name='$loc' id='$sNum' value=''>$tName</div>
        <div class='title'>$service</div>
    </div>
</td>";

<td class='right'>
    <div>
        <img src='../imgg' width='$wide'>
        <div class='num' valign='top' id='" . $sNum . ";'>$sNum</div>
        <div class='name' name='$loc' id='$sNum' value=''>$tName</div>
        <div class='title'>$service</div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

And the CSS is

```
.name{
    max-height: 19px;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-top: -42px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    font: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Vertical marquee perhaps?  ` <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up">Your scrolling text goes here</marquee>`

Comment: @DuaneLortie - the <marquee> tag has long been deprecated, is obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: but it does work :D

Comment: Ok. marquee is frowned upon as some browsers may stop supporting it. Instead see the vertical scroll example here 
http://www.quackit.com/css/codes/marquees/

Comment: This help? Someone needed help with a vertical marquee yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127096/css-marquee-not-showing-all-data?noredirect=1#answers-header

Comment: the quackit tut was kind close to what I am after. It does not indeed show the overflow which is hidden to work in the graphic, and currently it is scrolling way outta line with the background image, but I am sure that is a setting easy enough to find. Then I just have to figure out the overflow portion.